# $\bigcup X$ = $\sup(X)$ for a set $X$ of ordinals

Tags: elementary-set-theory, ordinals

Let $X$ be a set of ordinals. Prove that $\bigcup X$ = $\sup(X)$(which is the least ordinal
$\ge$ every ordinal in $X$).

Comment: Tried anything?

Answer (score 3):

Suppose first that $X$ has a maximal element $\mu$; then $\alpha\subseteq\mu$ for all $\alpha\in X$, so $\bigcup X=\mu$, and clearly $\mu=\sup X$.

Now assume that $X$ has no maximal element, and let $\mu=\sup X$. If $\xi\in\bigcup X$, there must be some $\alpha\in X$ such that $\xi\in\alpha$; and $\alpha\le\mu$, so $\alpha\subseteq\mu$, and therefore $\xi\in\mu$. Thus, $\bigcup X\subseteq\mu$. Now suppose that $\xi\in\mu$. Then $\xi<\mu$, so there is an $\alpha\in X$ such that $\xi<\alpha$, and hence $\xi\in\alpha\subseteq\bigcup X$. Thus, $\mu\subseteq\bigcup X$, and we have $\bigcup X=\mu$ in this case as well.

Comment: One question: the supremum is defined to be the least element of the upper bounds set (which should be a well-ordered set if the initial was). But this least element may not exists. In such a case, how do you define the supremum? Do you use the Axiom of choice or... ? How you define it? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

First we will check that $\bigcup X$ is also ordinal. To check this fact, we will prove that $\bigcup X$ is transitive and well-ordered with respect to $\in$.

If $y\in \bigcup X$ for all $y\in Y$, then there is some $x\in X$ satisfy that $y\in x$. By transitivity of $x$, we get $\bigcup y\in x$ so $\bigcup y  \in\bigcup X$ (because $x\subset \bigcup X$.) Therefore $\bigcup X$ is transitive.

Let $y,z\in\bigcup X$, then there is $x\in X$ such that $y,z\in x$ (because for every ordinal $\alpha$ and $\beta$ satisfy $\alpha\subset\beta$ or $\beta\subset \alpha$.) Since $y$ and $z$ are elements of ordinal so $x\in y$ or $x=y$ or $y\in x$ holds.

Finally, we will check that $\bigcup X$ is well-ordered by respect to $\in$. Let $A$ be a nonempty subset of $\bigcup X$. Since $A$ is nonempty, there is = $x\in X$ that intersects to $x$ (that is, $A\cap x\neq\varnothing$.) Consider $\alpha=\min (A\cap x)$ (this minimum exists because $A\cap x\subset x$ and $x$ is ordinal.)

Let $\beta \in A$. If $\beta\in x$ then definition of $\alpha$ we get $\alpha=\beta$ or $\alpha=\beta$. If not, we get $x\in\beta$ or $x=\beta$ (because $x$ and $\beta$ are ordinal.) In that cases we get $x\subset \beta$, so $\alpha\in\beta$. So $\alpha$ is the minimal element of $A$.

Therefore $\bigcup X$ is ordinal and $x \subset \bigcup X$ for all $x\in X$. If $x\subset y$ for all $x\in X$, then by transitivity of $y$ we get $\bigcup X\subset y$. Therefore $\bigcup X=\sup X$.

Comment: $\subset$ stands for proper subset?

Comment: @Mark No. I purpose the subset (possibly equal to the whole set.)

Comment: May I ask why $A$ is non-empty implies that $A\cap x\ne \emptyset$?

Comment: @Y.X. I've said that such $x$ exists. I've assumed that $A$ is a subset of $\bigcup X$, that is, $A$ is covered by elements of $X$.

Comment: @HanulJeon Actually I am asking about why such $x$ exists. Could you please explain why it can be covered by an element of X, rather than some union of the elements in X?

Comment: @Y.X. $A$ is a nonempty subset of $\bigcup X$, as I assumed and mentioned. Remind the definition of arbitrary union.

Comment: For me, you've argued that two same concepts are different.

Comment: @HanulJeon Oh, I see. Thanks a lot!