# If $\alpha$ is an ordinal number, prove that $\bigcup(\alpha+1)=\alpha$

Tags: set-theory, ordinals

The statement corresponds to  Theorem 124 of the appendix of Kelley's book *General Topology*:

> If $\alpha$ is an ordinal number, then $\bigcup(\alpha+1)=\alpha$.

My attempt:

$$\bigcup(\alpha+1)=\{\gamma:\exists\beta\in \alpha+1:\gamma\in\beta\}. $$

Because $\alpha+1$ is an ordinal number, the above equation can be rewritten as

$$\bigcup(\alpha+1)=\{\gamma:\gamma\in\alpha+1\}, $$

which is precisely $\alpha+1$.

Any help?

Thanks

Comment: Hint: note that $\beta<\alpha+1$ if and only if $\beta\leq \alpha$, i.e., iff $\beta\subseteq\alpha$.

Comment: Prove a more general theorem: If $X$ is a set of ordinals, then $\bigcup X=\sup X$. Next, deduce this claim by noting that $\sup X=\max X$ when $X$ has a last element, and $\alpha+1$ indeed has a last element.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: hahaha. ok. I would like also to prove that if $X$ is a set of ordinals, then $\bigcap X=\mbox{inf }X$. But yoy know, I have troubles proving $\bigcap X\in X$. :(

Comment: @AsafKaragila: It's really hard for me to start with oyur general theorem. Because, if $X$ has supremum, then $X$ should be ''finite'' in some way. I mean, $\mathbb N$ hasn't got supremum. On the other hand, $\{x\in\mathbb Q: x^2<2\}$ is also an infinite set but it has got a supremum (altought not a maximum). Any hint?

Comment: Verify the definition of an ordinal. Then use the hint Renan gave in the first comment.

Comment: Yes, if $X$ has a least element it was easy. The hard part was actually your generalization. However, there is a question asking precisely about that: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/537654/bigcup-x-supx-for-a-set-x-of-ordinals. Brian's answer helped me a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By definition, $\alpha + 1 = \alpha \cup \{\alpha\}$. Therefore,

\begin{align}
\bigcup(\alpha+1) &= \{\gamma:\exists\beta\in \alpha+1:\gamma\in\beta\} = \{\gamma:\exists\beta\in \alpha \cup \{\alpha\} :\gamma\in\beta\} \\
&= \{\gamma :\gamma\in\alpha\} = \alpha
\end{align}
where the equality $\{\gamma:\exists\beta\in \alpha \cup \{\alpha\} :\gamma\in\beta\} = \{\gamma :\gamma\in\alpha\}$ holds because:
\begin{align}
 \gamma \in \beta \text{ for some } \beta \in \alpha \cup \{\alpha\} &\iff \text{either } \gamma \in \beta \text{ for some } \beta \in \alpha, \text{ or } \gamma \in \alpha \\
&\iff \gamma \in \alpha  \quad\text{ ($\Rightarrow$ holds by transitivity of }\alpha\text{).}
\end{align}

In particular, note that $\alpha \notin \bigcup (\alpha+1)$ because $\alpha \notin \alpha$. The proof attempt in the OP is not valid because its last step  would mean that $\alpha \in \alpha$.

Comment: Nice answer btw.

Comment: Yes. I have noticed yoour remark following the tip of @ChrisCulter. Very good answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: You can "debug" your argument by setting $\alpha$ to be some small value, like $\alpha=1$. Run through all of your statements and inferences with this value. At some point you will find an incorrect statement, and it will point out where your argument is wrong.

Comment: Very useful answer. I have followed your tip and I have found my mistake. Thanks a lot. I have marked @Taroccoesbrocco's answer. However, let me say people (including me) need more hints and lees direct answers. So +100 to your answer. Thanks a lot.